# How to pick max number of oranges, optimally?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, logic

I am trying to solve a question:

> Jon has a series of baskets numbered 1 to N.  Each basked has few good oranges.  Jon wants to pick equal number of good oranges from each of the baskets from which he picks.  
>  
> He can start picking oranges from any of the baskets, but once he starts picking, he should pick from each of the consecutive baskets until he reaches the last basket he wants to pick from.  Find the max number of oranges that Jon can pick. 
>  
> For the input: `[80,50,82]`, the output should be `150` (50+50+50); while for `[8,40,77]`, it should be `80` (40+40).

My approach:

I am able to think of a brute-force approach - iterating over each of the baskets, I would check if we can pick those many oranges from all the right-hand side neighbors till the end (second para of the question) and see if we can pick any from the left.  And keep on doing this for each of the baskets, keeping track of the max oranges that we can pick.

This is an `O(n^2)` algorithm though.

Could we do any better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is O(n) solution.

Start traversing array from right and the idea is to keep track of minFound as you move left. Also, keep on updating the maxOranges found so far with each new position moving left.

```
    int arr[3] = {8,40,77};
    
    int length = 3;
    
    
    int minFound = arr[length-1];
    int maxOranges = minFound;
    int i=length-2;
    while(i>=0) {
        if(arr[i] < minFound) {
            minFound = arr[i];
            
        }
        int currOranges = (length-i)*minFound;
        if(currOranges > maxOranges) {
            maxOranges = currOranges;
        }
        i--;
    }
    
    cout<<maxOranges;
```

Comment: You say, "...start traversing from left..." - where are you doing that in the code above?  You traverse from the _right to the left_.

Comment: My bad. Start traversing from right and move to left.

Comment: @UmedhSinghBundela if this meets your question requirements, can you mark this as solution

Comment: I don't think you have to pick from *all* the remaining boxes, i.e, given [1,10,1,10,1], you could pick 20 from the 2nd and 4th.

Comment: I think we have to pick all baskets till last basket. If thats not the case, my solution is incorrect.

Comment: @Matt Timmermans  "from each of the **consecutive** baskets", so in your example the best is 10. But for [1,10,5,10,1], we can reach 15 due to "until he reaches the **last basket he wants** to pick from", So problem is for maximizing `minimum_at_interval*interval_length`

Comment: @MBo, how 15?  Shouldn't it be 5 (1 each from basket)?  In other words, I interpreted **last basked he wants to pick from** as the last basket in the array - is that not the case?  Also, I think this answer considers it till the end of the array.

Comment: @RajatSharma, good idea about calculating `currOranges`.  In the logic that I was thinking about, I just thought about the `if(arr[i] < minFound) minFound = arr[i];` part and was not sure where to stop updating `minFound`.  Could you please share your intuition about calculating `currOranges` while updating `minFound`?

Comment: @Umedh Singh Bundela  I believe `he wants to pick from` means that Jon can stop before the end to provide better result. So result for 1 10 1 10 1 is 10 from a single basket, for 1,10,5,10,1 result is 5+5+5=15

Answer (score 1):

This problem is equivalent to "largest area rectangle in histogram" and might be solved in linear time using "increasing" stack.

The largest amount of oranges taken from every basket from continuous sequence is equal to the number of oranges in the some basket (`minoranges`). Put indexes of candidates in a stack.

When we find larger basket than stack contains (stack top contains its index), it definitely continues "good sequence", and we add its index to the stack (perhaps it will "the smallest" in future).

When we meet smaller basket than stack top, it breaks some "good sequences" and we can remove larger candidates from the stack - they will not have chance later. Remove stack top until smaller basket is met, and calculate potential amount of oranges during this process  - for all ranges starting from stack candidates and ending at the current index.

Note that stack always contains indexes of strictly increasing sequence of the numbers of oranges in basket, so we don't need to consider items before index at the stack top (intermediate result) in calculation of orange amount (they will be considered later with another `minoranges` value).

Every item is pushed onto stack and removed once, so `O(n)` linear time and space complexity.

```
baskets = [1,10,5,10,1]
stack = []
best_oranges = 0
for i in range(len(baskets)):
    while (len(stack) > 0) and (baskets[stack[-1]] >= baskets[i]): #smaller basket is met
        minoranges = baskets[stack.pop()]
        if len(stack) == 0:
            start_idx = 0
        else:
            start_idx = stack[-1]+ 1
        #range_length * smallest_weight_in_range
        best_oranges = max(best_oranges, minoranges * (i - start_idx))
    stack.append(i)
print(best_oranges)
```

Comment: That's another good way to solve it.  Thank you, @MBo!